# How do I recover files from SD Card that went from one camera to another?

Tags: memory-card, sdcard, data-corruption, file-recovery

A couple of years ago, I made the mistake of transferring my SD card from one camera (a Polaroid point-and-shoot that had low battery charge at the time) to another (an AGFA Photo point-and-shoot). I had no idea the files would be damaged, so I learned the hard way not to share SD cards between different cameras. :(

At one point, I was still able to review photos on the computer, but now the jpegs seem completely unreadable. I am still able to open the SD  card on my computer, but the files yield the same error message that I am unable to view the image.

I've tried Zero Assumption Recovery. It was able to retrieve a few files, but from a different session.

Is there any other way for me to get my photos back?

Answer (score 2):

Moving the card between cameras is not likely to cause a problem. I think that's just a red herring. You might try some different recovery tool, but it seems likely that what you've gotten is as good as it's going to get.  Time to get another card, and in the future remember to upload to a computer frequently and keep backups.